# How to get and set Mouse Position in RDP?

Tags: c#, .net, rdp

I'm looking for a way to get and set the mouse position on a Remote Desktop. Usually I can use user32's functions such as GetCursorPos and SetCursorPos, but when my RDP is minimized, those functions throw an InvalidOperationException.

I have tried setting a registry key (RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized) on my machine to keep session alive, as explained [here](https://sahipro.com/docs/faq/remote-desktop-connection.html). But this didn't solve my problem.

Is there any mouse API that work with RDP? Or any configuration I could use?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142166/explain-errors-from-getkeystate-getcursorpos

Comment: It is, for information's sake. I didn't know GetCursorInfo would work differently. But that didn't solve the issue so far. Thank you anyways :)